# Check string value isblank or null in lightning Component's controller

Tags: lightning, string, method

In Lightning Component controller checking blank and undefined for a string variable.

```
 var AccAsset = component.find("AccountAsset").get("v.value");

 if(String.isBlank(AccAsset) || AccAsset == 'undefined'){
        component.set("v.hasError", true);
  }
```

This is throwing an error

> "String.isBlank is not a function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, there is no function like `String.isBlank()`. But you can check it like

```
if (AccAsset) {
    //do something
}
```

If you want you can write a function like below

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

Remember `isEmpty('undefined')` returns false, but `isEmpty(undefined)` returns true.

Comment: In this, if (AccAsset) AccAsset Treat as boolean but my variable is return string

Comment: In js these are considered as false `null,undefined,0,000,"",false` so if you add some string value in `AccAsset`  say `AccAsset = 'abcd'`, it will considered as true. for non zero number it returns true, for non null object true as well.

Answer (score 2):

`$A.util.isEmpty()` checks null,blank,empty& undefined too, so best fit for your use case.

```
 if($A.util.isEmpty(component.find("AccountAsset").get("v.value"))){
        component.set("v.hasError", true);
  }
```